# Is it possible to test a bool against 2 variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if (a == ("A" or "U")):
 do something
```

but it only tests against "A" when I introduce the input in the console

but it works if I do this:

```
if (a == "A" or a == "U")):
 do something
```

is it possible to achieve the second with a simpler line like the first one?
thanks!

Comment: `any` might be helpful if you have many values to test.

Comment: if a in ["A", "U"]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't check both the conditions using `(a == ("A" or "U"))`** because when you execute `"A" or "U"` in python interpreter you will get `"A"` (the first truthy value) similarly when you execute `"A" and "U"` you will get `"U"` (the last truthy value).

If you want simplified expression, you can use,

```
if a in ("A", "U"):
    # TODO: perform a task
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`: This will be simpler

```sh
if a in ('A', 'U'):
    #do something
```

Understanding your code.

```sh
if (a == ("A" or "U")):
   # do something
```

Python checks for  `"A" or "U"` which `"A"` is return because of how truthfulness works. If the first is true, then the `or` is not evaluated. Since only empty string is False, the first none empty string will be selected and there your code is equivalent to:

```sh
if (a == "A"):
   # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to python. You can't further simplify the 2nd equation.

a == "A" is one boolean -> x
a == "U" is one boolean -> y

x || y -> simplified version.

Also, you can't apply distributive law to equality Operators(==, <, >).

You can use the membership operator `in` check achieve above.

```
if a in ["A", "U"]:
  do_something()
```